# Module for overriding Mage Core Encryption Model

Tags: php, magento

I want to override/extend `Mage_Core_Encryption_Model` to handle Legacy Passwords.

I'm migrating old sites data into magento. My old site encryption method is Sha-1. but magento use md5 + text in core encryption method. I have changed the core module manually and migrate correctly but now i want to create a custom module for that (migrate without encryption, after migration override the md5 method by sha-1)

How can I create a custom module for that that overwrites the core code I have changed?

Comment: and what part gives you the trouble here? Cool to know what you are up to, leave such short QA questions to twitter next time? Try to explain your goal and what you have done so far here.

Comment: I'm migrating old sites data into magento. My old site encryption method is Sha-1. but magento use md5 + text in core encryption  method. i have change core module manually and migrate correctly. but  now i want to create a custom module for that.(migrate without encryption, after migration override the md5 method by sha-1)  Have any idea to create a custom module for this requirement?

Comment: edited your question :) now think how on earth should anyone know those details when you asked first?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need a module to replace the md5 hash mechanism in Magento with sha1?

I wont go into creating an entire module here, but simply the key parts.  If you are interested though as a complete example to reference, I created a module a while back which replaces the md5 hash with sha512 that you can look at - https://github.com/drewhunter/BetterHash - you would obviously need to slightly modify it to handle sha1)

So essentially you need to override the [hash()](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php#L83) method of `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption`

Your modules config.xml will require the following:

**File:** app/code/local/Yourcompany/Yourmodule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Yourcompany_Yourmodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Yourcompany_Yourmodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <core>
                <encryption_model>Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Hash</encryption_model>
            </core>  
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then to take advantage of the rewrite:

**File:** app/code/local/Yourcompany/Yourmodule/Model/Hash.php

```
<?php

class Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Hash extends Mage_Core_Model_Encryption
{
    public function hash($data)
    {
        return sha1($data);
    }
}
```